# Update directive's template on controller's variable change - angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

What I'm trying to do is to get a JSON object from a $http request, requested inside a controller, and build a directive that displays the multiple objects in the JSON object in a grid.

The problem is that when the object arrives, I have to process it in the directive's controller to be able to use it in the template, as such, when the JSON object changes, it is not reflected in the template. How can I make the directive know about a change in the object and force it to reload the template?

```
// The Directive code
amobile.directive('grid', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        break: '=break',
        source: '=source'
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
        var source = $scope.source;
        $scope.final_data = new Array(source.length);
        if(source){
            for(var j=0; j < source.length; ++j){
                var total = Math.ceil(source[j]['Division'].length / $scope.break);
                var data = new Array(total);
                for (var i = 0; i < total; ++i) {
                    data[i] = source[j]['Division'].slice(i * $scope.break, (i + 1) * $scope.break);
                }
                $scope.final_data[j] = data;
            }
        }

    },
    templateUrl:'directives/grid.tpl.html',
    replace: true
};
});

//The template
<div ng-repeat="data in final_data">
<div layout="vertical" layout-sm="horizontal" layout-padding class="" ng-repeat="row in data">
    <div class="" ng-repeat="item in row">
        <div flex style="width:100px">
            {{item.name}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
//index.html
<div ng-controller="DivisionsCtrl as div">
    <material-button ng-click="div.go()" class="material-theme-red">Button</material-button>
<div ng-if="div.data.floors">
  <gridy break="3" source="div.data.floors"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the simplest solution would be to use watch

```
controller: function($scope) {
    processData = function () {
      var source = $scope.source;
      $scope.final_data = new Array(source.length);
      if(source){
        for(var j=0; j < source.length; ++j){
            var total = Math.ceil(source[j]['Division'].length / $scope.break);
            var data = new Array(total);
            for (var i = 0; i < total; ++i) {
                data[i] = source[j]['Division'].slice(i * $scope.break, (i + 1) * $scope.break);
            }
            $scope.final_data[j] = data;
        }
      }
    }
  $scope.$watch('div.data.floors', processData, true)

},
```

Comment: The code as it is doesn't work. When I change the object and press the button to update the view, I can receive the new object (through Firebug) but the view doesn't update.